# How do I Prove De Morgan's Law with Inference?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to get from ~(q -> p) to (q ^ ~p), which is a version of De Morgan's Law with the conditional, in Fitch using only basic logic rules (e.g. ^ intro, ^ elim, etc. No laws or shortcuts).

(Actually specifically I'm trying to get from ~(~q -> p) to (~q ^ ~p), but that's the same idea, right?)

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to write the math correctly. But $q\to p$ is not the same as $q\wedge\neg p$. Did you mean $\color{red}{\neg}(q\to p)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the negation of the conditional

Comment: Okay, so please edit your question accordingly by clicking on "edit" (remember to use MathJax).

Comment: Can we use the fact that $q\to p\equiv\neg q\vee p$?

Comment: No, no laws or shortcuts, only "and" "or" "conditional" "negation" "biconditional" introduction or elimination

Comment: I tried mathjax to change to \rightarrow but it didn't work. Do I need some other notation?

Comment: Enclose your in-line LaTeX in single dollar signs.  E.g. "\$ \lnot( q \rightarrow p) \$" (without the quotations marks) becomes $\lnot( q \rightarrow p)$  (note that \to is easier to write than \rightarrow as long as you're not needing other arrow directions.)

Comment: You can also use `\gets` for the other arrow direction ( $\gets$ ) if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

You seek to derive $\neg q\wedge\neg p$ from the premise $\neg(\neg q\to p)$.   Well, derive each conjunct separately then introduce the conjunction.

First show that you can derive $\neg q\to p$ from an assumption of $p$.   Therefore you can infer that $\neg p$ may be derived from $\neg(\neg q\to p)$.

Next show that you can derive $\neg q\to p$ from an assumption of $q$.   Therefore you can infer that $\neg q$ may be derived from $\neg(\neg q\to p)$.

Here's a quick Fitch style skeleton of the proof.   Fill in the missing details and you are done.

$$\fitch{\neg(\neg q\to p)}{\fitch{p}{~\vdots\\\neg q\to p\\\bot}\\\neg p\\\fitch{q}{~\vdots\\\neg q\to p\\\bot}\\\neg q\\\neg q\wedge\neg p}$$

Comment: We shouldn't prove $\neg(q\to p)$ instead of $\neg(\neg q\to p)$?

Comment: @manooooh Not when the second is "actually specifically" what Valentine Fox seeks.

Answer (score -1):

DeMorgan's Laws are pretty much your only means of distributing a negation by inference; you can't prove them by the same.

Fortunately, they're both intuitive and can be proven by other means, such as truth tables.

As far as your expression, $!(!q -> p) = !q!p$, that's easily proven if DeMorgan's laws are allowed. $x -> y = !x + y$, so your expression is actually $!(q + p) = !q!p$, which is DeMorgan's law verbatim.

Comment: No, De Morgan's laws often can, and have gotten proved from other rules of inference using natural deduction type systems.  Plenty of other types of systems can derive them also.